# Is there any way to find tweet's count on monthly basis?

Tags: java, android, twitter

I want to find user tweet's count for each month from the time when user create an account..?
Is there any way to find this.?
Give some solution...Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [user_timeline API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

It doesn't provide a direct way to get or count tweets by month, but you can get a *limited* number of tweets from a given user, then check the dates to see which month they fall into.

You can also limit the results by tweetID, which might allow you to step through historical results, though not month-by-month.

Answer (score 1):

95% confident that it isn't possible. The REST Api does not include such a method and I didn't find statistics methods either. Streaming API shouldn't help too.

And, twitter default search only goes back a week, so it won't be possible to create a statistic by simply loading all tweets from a user.

The remaining 5% is reserved for using a different service. Here's an article that might help:

- [All the easiest ways to search old tweets](http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/)

Answer (score 1):

You can view your tweet counts per month here
It also provides extra stats for you, e.g. retweet, reply counts, etc.
http://www.tweetstats.com